# MySql SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS disabling the order by clause

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. It seems to be disabling the order by clause.

MySql
Server version: 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (

disables the  ORDER BY clause

I see it was supposed to be fixed.

Anyone have an ideal on how I can fix this issue?

Thanks
Phil

http://www.michikono.com/2007/08/07/the-secret-of-sql_calc_found_rows/

Posted by Wade Bowmer on May 14 2006 11:40pm
Be aware that using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() disables ORDER BY … LIMIT optimizations (see bugs http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18454 and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19553). Until it’s fixed, you should run your own benchmarks with and without it.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18454

Comment: Use a separate count(*) as was suggested...

Comment: separate count(*) does not work. The issue is the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS works great with FOUND_ROWS(). ORDER BY does not work with the combination.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, *"disables the ORDER BY clause"* ...? These bug reports don't mention anything about incorrect ordering.  And yes, a separate `COUNT()` *does* work. Why would it not?  You have to specify the same `WHERE`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an answer for this issue. I just updated my select and it is not an issue.

I did open a bug on mysql.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85530

Good luck. 
Phil